Kafka NodeJS Application running in Minikube fails with "connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.1.1:9092" when Producing an event
I'm running Kafka through Zookeeper on my local Linux machine and my NodeJs application is running in a Pod of Minikube on the same machine.
I set the code up like below:
server.ts:
const fanoutKafka = new Kafka({
  clientId: "timeline",
  brokers: ["host.minikube.internal:9092"], 
});

export const fanoutProducer = fanoutKafka.producer();
fanoutProducer.connect();

timeline.ts
fanoutProducer.send({
            topic: kafka_fanout_topic,
            messages: [
                {
                    key: msg.postId,
                    value: JSON.stringify(msg)
                }
            ]
        })

It connects to Kafka Producer in server.ts, but it fails when I try to publish from timeline.ts inside the pod. But if I try with 127.0.0.1:9092 and npm start it works without any issue.
As well as if I try with minikube ssh it works too:
docker@minikube:~$ nc -vz host.minikube.internal 9092
Connection to host.minikube.internal (192.168.49.1) 9092 port [tcp/*] succeeded!

Here is the full stacktrace from the pod:
KafkaJSNonRetriableError
  Caused by: KafkaJSConnectionError: Connection error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.1.1:9092
    at Socket.onError (/usr/src/app/node_modules/kafkajs/src/network/connection.js:210:23)
    ... 3 lines matching cause stack trace ...
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  name: 'KafkaJSNumberOfRetriesExceeded',
  retriable: false,
  helpUrl: undefined,
  retryCount: 5,
  retryTime: 14476,
  [cause]: KafkaJSConnectionError: Connection error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.1.1:9092
      at Socket.onError (/usr/src/app/node_modules/kafkajs/src/network/connection.js:210:23)
      at Socket.emit (node:events:519:28)
      at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:169:8)
      at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:128:3)
      at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
    retriable: true,
    helpUrl: undefined,
    broker: 'some-random-name',
    code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
    [cause]: undefined
  }

Wondering how it resolves to 127.0.1.1 while Producing an event?
NB: Like I said Procuder.connect() is not causing any issue.

Please show your Kafka setup. Have you researched what advertised.listeners setting is used for?
